# A die is loaded in such away an a probability

Tags: probability, statistics

A die is loaded in such away that even number is twice as likely to occur as an odd number. Let A be the event that an even number turns up and B be the event that a number divisible by 3 occurs.

Find $P(A \cap B)$ and $P(A \cup B)$

Please help me 
I did not know how to solve it..

Thanks all

Comment: The data is insufficient to determine these quantities.

Comment: Hint: We cannot solve the problem unless we assume that every odd number has the same probability $p$. Then each even number has probability $2p$. We have $p+p+p+2p+2p+2p=1$, and therefore $p=\frac{1}{9}$.

Comment: It says even number is twice as likely to occur as an odd number. I interpreted the unclear wording as meaning that *any* even number is twice as likely to occur as *any* odd number.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I get it thank you !

Comment: You are welcome.